# How to replace %0A with br from querystring?

Tags: replace

Im trying to replace a %0A with a br to display linebreaks in a mail.
Im sending a text from a textarea value as a querystring to an .asp page with javascript and I see the querystring sending word%0Anextword%0Anextword, but when I try to replace it in the .asp page, no replacement is done.

The querystring that is sent to the asp page from the javascript:

```
text=word%0Anextword
```

and I try to replace the querystring in the asp page like this:

```
texten=replace(request.querystring("texten"),"%0A","<br>")
```

I have tryed with HtmlEncoding, tryed to replace \n, \r\n etc, but nothing works?
Any input really appriciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use chr(10). In whatever language you need :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
replace(text,VbCrLf,"<br>")
```

A better solution may involve not reading the input from a querystring, change your form to POST and then use

```
message = Request.Form("text")
```