# Whats the codeURI value for ¶?

Tags: c#, javascript

Could someone please tell me what the CodeURI value of a line break is? (¶)

**If you look below at the comment test you will see what i'm trying to achieve.**

```
public static string unescapeForEncodeUriCompatability(string str) {
      return str.Replace("%21", "!").Replace("%7e", "~")
          .Replace("%27", "'").Replace("%28", "(").Replace("%29", ")")
          .Replace("%3b", ";").Replace("%2f", "/").Replace("%3f", "?")
          .Replace("%3a", ":").Replace("%40", "@").Replace("%26", "&")
          .Replace("%3d", "=").Replace("%2b", "+").Replace("%24", "$")
          .Replace("%2c", ",").Replace("%23", "#"); //test .Replace("¶"," ")
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just do a normal URI decode?

Comment: I'm done, all i need is the one char change, what do you mean normal URI decode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe its `%B6`

Line breaks in text are generally represented in three ways as either \r\n or as \n or \r.

ck this [out](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

**ADDED LATER**
as @w0lf said i came across [this](http://www.web-manual.net/lamp-architecture/security/url-encoded-characters-such-as/) and a [stackoverfow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751155/how-to-replace-0a-with-br-from-querystring) so it seems like

```
%B6 is the character "¶". For newlines use %0A or %0D%0A (LF or CRLF)
```

Hope this helps someone.Thankz @w0lf

Comment: %B6 is the character "¶". For newlines use %0A or %0D%0A (LF or CRLF)

Comment: @Pomster ck out @ w0lf 's comment.Does that solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
    encodeURIComponent('yoursymbolgoeshere');
```

I got "%C2%B6" running it in chrome console

Comment: @Pomster I think what he's saying is `.Replace("%C2%B6","¶")`

Comment: The URI code is the same, I just used javascript to attain the URI code. Try what the above comment suggets. I'm interested to know if it works.